# Can Macbook air run my softwares?

Tags: macos, mac, snow-leopard, macbook-pro

### I would like to buy Macbook air with below specifications

```
4gb RAM
128GB Flash Storage
i5 Processor
1.7Ghz 
Mavericks OS
```

---

### And i would like to install the below softwares

```
x-Code
2 Virtual machines (Windows & Ubuntu) using parallels.
Adobe Photoshop
Adobe illustrator 
2 Web Browsers
Skype
Microsoft Office 2010.
```

---

Will Apple macbook air run above mentioned softwares without making laptop slow ?

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question. Much will depend on how you use each application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty subjective question, especially when dealing with virtual machines and Photoshop/Illustrator. Both of these can take quite a bit of RAM, especially the Windows VM and PS/IL when dealing with large images. I'd recommend getting the 8GB RAM version if you're planning to run all of these simultaneously and editing large or layered images. Also, the SSD might be a bit too small for two VMs, but this depends on what kind of VMs you run (Windows XP/7/8, Linux server or desktop, amount of applications you install etc.).

I'm running the same kind of software on my Air, but it's a i7, 8GB, 256GB SSD version, and I've had no trouble with it.